# Does "between" also mean "by the way", after the Internet abbreviation?

Tags: meaning

One famous internet abbreviation is *btw* meaning *by the way*.

For a long time, I read *btw* as *between*. At one point, I use to imagined *between* also has the meaning *by the way*. I am realizing it wasn't just me. Many have had the same problem, as I realized on the Internet.

Does *between* also mean *by the way* now?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: There are certainly contexts where ***on** the way* can mean "between" (current location and intended destination).

Comment: Can you add some examples to illustrate this part of the question: "I am realizing it wasn't just me. Many have had the same problem, as I realized on the Internet."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard abbreviation for *between* is [*betw.*](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/#b) [BTW](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/BTW) is an acronym or abbreviation for just under fifty phrases, names, businesses, government agencies, etc., including a non-standard abbreviation for *between* and the internet use as *by the way*. Sharing the same abbreviation does not, by some lexical alchemy, transform one thing into another.

So *between* is still *between* and *by the way* is still *by the way* no matter how they're abbreviated.